# Incrementing AtomicInteger in Java in 1000 threads does not generate value 1000

Tags: java, multithreading

I am executing a java code where I have an `AtomicInteger` on which 1000 threads are trying to perform an `incrementAndGet()`. I was expecting the final value to be 1000. But each run is generating all sorts of different values. The code is as follows :

```
class task implements Runnable {
    AtomicInteger i ;
    task(AtomicInteger ai) {i =ai ;}
    public void run() { i.incrementAndGet() ; }
}

class jlt {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        AtomicInteger atomicInt = new AtomicInteger(0);

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        for(int i=1; i<=1000; i++)
            executor.submit(new task(atomicInt)) ;

        executor.shutdown() ;

        System.out.println(atomicInt.get()); // 1000 is expected 
    }
}
```

I am not able to figure out the mistake that I am making here or in my understanding

Comment: Unrelated: A) read about java naming conventions - class names go UpperCase B) always always use braces for loop/if/... blocks. Even when there is just one line. It is so easy to get this wrong.

Comment: Also note that you only have 2 threads incrementing the counter, not 1000.

Comment: And the real answer here: don't assume what some library method does. Read its javadoc. It is very clearly documented what `shutdown()` is doing.

Comment: I wanted to add that `submit()` will return a `Future` which you could add to a list. Once you've submitted all operations you can loop through the list of Futures calling `get()` which will block until it's completed running

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()

> Initiates an orderly shutdown in which previously submitted tasks are executed, but no new tasks will be accepted. Invocation has no additional effect if already shut down.
>   This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use `awaitTermination` to do that.

That means that when you call `atomicInt.get()` not all threads have been executed and some had no chance of incrementing the AtomicInteger.

Answer (score 10):

You're not waiting for the threads to finish before printing out the number.

Add a `executor.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)` after `shutdown()` and you might see something that you expected.

Comment: Or read that duplicated question ;-)